# Simple host to guest connection with QEMU

Tags: linux, networking, qemu

I am using qemu to emulate a custom linux system (generated with buildroot) and I would like to export display of my application on my host machine.

This seems pretty simple but I have been stuck for a few days reading documentation and post on stack exchange and I haven't been able to find a solution.

I do not need the guest to access external network, I just want the host and guest to communicate with each other.

Following the qemu documentation, I tried SLIRP and tun/tap networking but I wasn't able tomake anything work.

I also tried the '-redir' option for port forwarding for ssh, but no result either.

For more information :
- the host machine is a ubuntu 16.04
- ifconfig -a, on the guest shows me the lo and tunl0 interfaces but no eth0 interface. I haven't been able to understand what tunl0 is, as it shows all the time even with the '-net none' option.
- I have added as modules the virtio drivers for the guest.

right now, I am using the following line to launch qemu :

```
qemu-system-x86_system -kernel bzImage -initrd initrd.gz -drive id=disk,file=image.img,if=none -device ahci,id=ahci -device ide-drive,drive=disk,bus=ahci.0 -m 2048 -net nic -net tap,ifname=tap0,script=no,downscript=no
```

I tried setting the tap interface manually :

```
tunctl -u $USER
ifconfig tap0 <gateway ip> up
```

EDIT :
I also tried to follow step by step the arch linux tutorials :
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_bridge
and 
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/QEMU

But still, no ethernet interface...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I finally found out the what the problem was. If any one is interested, here is the answer.

As stated, I generate my linux image using Buildroot and I misconfigured the kernel. I needed to add some drivers for ethernet, in order to be able to have the eth0 interface. Now, that I know it it, it actually seems pretty obvious.
More details here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33337062/buildroot-ip-cant-find-device-eth0

Also, that solved another problem I had with /etc/resolv.conf that was missing on VM.

Hope that helps someone... one day. :)